# How do I connect to a proxy using OpenSSL TLS?

Tags: c, proxy, openssl

I've recently started using OpenSSL for TLS communications in client/server fashion and I now want to implement support for connecting through a proxy. I was wondering how one could write an OpenSSL based program that could connect through a proxy and use TLS for endpoint encryption. I've searched and not found anything on the internet except using OpenSSL's s_client to connect through a proxy, so it is theoretically possible. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: take a look at openssl s_client code in openssl 1.1.0 and above

Comment: Smart. Will do.